# how to define function in fortran 90

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to define a function in my module code and call it in the main fortran code but when I want to compile my code I'm receiving this error :

> This actual argument must be the name of an external user function or the name of an intrinsic function.

and my function is :

```
Function func (x)  
   implicit none  
   double precision func,x  
   func=x  
   RETURN  
end function func
```

and in the main code

```
call Romberg (dra,func,ra(mm),ra(kk))
```

I want to measure the destance between `ra(mm)` & `ra(kk)`

Comment: How is `func` defined inside the subroutine `Romberg`?

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
external func
```

in the caller. This tells the caller that "func" is an external procedure. You evidently have Romberg declared with an explicit interface specifying the argument is a procedure.